# GWT program not running

Tags: gwt

When I run my project I get the following error:
Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell

I have already installed the google plugin with the sdk's and GWT designer.
I am not understanding due to what this error is occuring?

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell` is deprecated and no longer used in later versions of GWT.

[`com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#an_example_launch) is the one to be used for launch GWT Dev Mode.

**References -**

1. **Simple Compiling and Debuggig** - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging
2. Advanced **[SuperDevMode](http://geekbybit.blogspot.in/2013/03/diy-working-with-gwt-codeserver-tomcat.html)** - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#SuperDevMode

Comment: Problem solved.Just downloaded the new gwt sdk zip and added the jar files.