# How to specify com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode as the main class automatically when debug gwt code

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

when I debug my gwt application code using google eclipse plugin via

selected gwt module->debug as->web application,

the generated debug configuration always use **com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell** as the main class. This makes my debug failed as **GWTShell** is a deprecated class ([GWT program not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086947/gwt-program-not-running)).

Now I have to manually change the main class to **com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode** in the "debug configurations" again and again whenever I need to debug.

I would like to know how to make google eclipse plugin set the correct main class **DevMode** automatically.

I am using Eclipse J2EE 4.3.2 Kepler and the gwt sdk is version 2.6.0.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the Google Plugin for Eclipse cannot determine the version of your GWT, and falls back to assuming it's an ancient version, where DevMode didn't exist yet and GWTShell should be used.

Update to GWT 2.6.1 (download the SDK from http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html and configure it in Eclipse) to fix the issue.

See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8556